# find xml element by attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, traversal

Using JQuery or Javascript how would I return 'Mary Boone' from the xml below starting out with the show 'id' attribute of '2'?

I'm thinking something along the lines of -

```
var result = xml.getElementByAttribute("2").gallery.text();
```

the XML:

```
<shows>
    <show id="1">
        <artist>Andreas Gursky</artist>
        <gallery>Matthew Marks</gallery>
        <medium>photography</medium>
    </show>
<show id="2">
        <artist>Eric Fischl</artist>
        <gallery>Mary Boone</gallery>
        <medium>painting</medium>
    </show>
</shows>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With jQuery, you could do:

```
var result = $(xml).find("show[id=2] > gallery").text();
```

As in:

```
$.ajax({
    url:'/path/to/file.xml',
    success:function(xml) {
        var result = $(xml).find("show[id=2] > gallery").text();
        alert(result);
    }
});
```

**EDIT:** Added the `>` to the selector. Not required, but a little better.