# Parse xml - child items not being parsed

Tags: jquery, xml

I am new to xml and stuck, hope someone could advise. Only the header is being displayed, but not any of the child items. I think my error is here:

```
var topicid = $(xml).find('content name="title"').text();
```

Does anyone have some ideas?

The JS is:

```
$.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "http://wsearch.nlm.nih.gov/ws/query?db=healthTopics&term=asthma",
            dataType: "xml",
            cache: false,
            success: function(xml) {

            // Get header data
                var name = $(xml).find('nlmSearchResult').text();

                $('#headername').html('<b>' + name + '</b>');



            // Reset detail div
            $('#detaildata').text('');

            // Loop through the detaildata and find all prod nodes
            $(xml).find('detaildata').each(function(){

                // Move detail data into internal variables         
                var topicid = $(xml).find('content name="title"').text();
                var fullsummary = $(xml).find('content name="FullSummary"').text();
                var alsocalled = $(xml).find('content name="altTitle"').text();


                $('#detaildata').append(
                    "<b>" + topicid + "</b>" + " - " 
                    + "Also known as: " + alsocalled + " - "
                    + fullsummary
                    + "<br>"
                    );

            });        


            },
```

The xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<nlmSearchResult>
    <term>asthma</term>
    <file>viv_u1cZOb</file>
    <server>pvlbsrch15</server>
    <count>65</count>
    <retstart>0</retstart>
    <retmax>10</retmax>
    <list num="65" start="0" per="10">
        <document rank="0" url="http://www.nlm.nih.gov/medlineplus/asthma.html">
            <content name="title">&lt;span class="qt0"&gt;Asthma&lt;/span&gt;</content>
            <content name="organizationName">National Library of Medicine</content>
            <content name="altTitle">Bronchial &lt;span class="qt0"&gt;Asthma&lt;/span&gt;</content>
            <content name="FullSummary">&lt;p&gt;&lt;span class="qt0"&gt;Asthma&lt;/span&gt; is a chronic disease that affects your airways. Your airways are tubes that carry air in and out of your lungs. If you have &lt;span class="qt0"&gt;asthma&lt;/span&gt;, the inside walls of your airways become sore and swollen. That makes them very sensitive, and they may react strongly to things that you are allergic to or find irritating. When your airways react, they get narrower and your lungs get less air.&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;Symptoms of &lt;span class="qt0"&gt;asthma&lt;/span&gt; include&lt;/p&gt;&lt;ul&gt;&lt;li&gt;Wheezing&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt;Coughing, especially early in the morning or at night&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt;Chest tightness&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt;Shortness of breath&lt;/li&gt;&lt;/ul&gt;&lt;p&gt;Not all people who have &lt;span class="qt0"&gt;asthma&lt;/span&gt; have these symptoms. Having these symptoms doesn't always mean that you have &lt;span class="qt0"&gt;asthma&lt;/span&gt;. Your doctor will diagnose &lt;span class="qt0"&gt;asthma&lt;/span&gt; based on lung function tests, your medical history, and a physical exam. You may also have allergy tests.&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;When your &lt;span class="qt0"&gt;asthma&lt;/span&gt; symptoms become worse than usual, it's called an &lt;span class="qt0"&gt;asthma&lt;/span&gt; attack. Severe &lt;span class="qt0"&gt;asthma&lt;/span&gt; attacks may require emergency care, and they can be fatal.&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;&lt;span class="qt0"&gt;Asthma&lt;/span&gt; is treated with two kinds of medicines: quick-relief medicines to stop &lt;span class="qt0"&gt;asthma&lt;/span&gt; symptoms and long-term control medicines to prevent symptoms. &lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;NIH: National Heart, Lung, and Blood Institute&lt;/p&gt;</content>
```

...
...

Comment: Please see [FindElementAttribute](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3024276/find-xml-element-by-attribute)

Comment: Hi Siddique - are you ruggesting it should be: var topicid = $(xml).find('nlmSearchResult > content name="title"').text();

Comment: $(xml).find('content[name="title"]').text()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have two issues

The first is on this line:

```
$(xml).find('detaildata').each(function(){
```

I don't see any **detaildata** elements in your XML. That would mean that nothing would be selected and the `.each()` has nothing to iterate over, so the anonymous function that you expect to append content to `$('#detaildata')` is not ever being called.

The second issue is that you also need to adjust how you are finding the elements that have attribute values to use the [Attribute Equals Selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/):

```
$(xml).find('content[name="title"]')
```

Try this:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://wsearch.nlm.nih.gov/ws/query?db=healthTopics&term=asthma",
        dataType: "xml",
        cache: false,
        success: function(xml) {

        // Get header data
        var name = $(xml).find('nlmSearchResult').text();

        $('#headername').html('<b>' + name + '</b>');

        // Reset detail div
        $('#detaildata').text('');

        // Move detail data into internal variables         
        var topicid = $(xml).find('content[name="title"]').text();
        var fullsummary = $(xml).find('content[name="FullSummary"]').text();
        var alsocalled = $(xml).find('content[name="altTitle"]').text();

        $('#detaildata').append(
                "<b>" + topicid + "</b>" + " - " 
                + "Also known as: " + alsocalled + " - "
                + fullsummary
                + "<br>"
            );
    });
```